# How to shutdown TPL Dataflow on fatal exception, in a gracefully way?

Tags: c#, exception, pipeline, tpl-dataflow

I am using a sequential pipeline build on TPL Dataflow, that consists in 3 blocks:

- B1 - prepares the message
- B2 - posts the message to a remote service
- B3 - saves the result

The problem is how to shutdown the pipeline, when an error like service down occurs. The pipeline  must go down in a controlled manner, so no results from B2 are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple but took me few rounds before i got it, since there is not much information behind basic library information at Microsoft site.

Hope it helps someone. The solution can be easily reconfigured to meet other requirements.

The approach presented relies on:

- `CancellationTokenSource` to signal shutdown.
  Each block, in the case of a fatal exception, should signal a shutdown through a shared `CancellationTokenSource` object.
- Blocks that should stop to work immediately after signal should be initialized passing the shared `CancellationTokenSource`  object
- The program must wait for the final block to end all message processing.

Here the solution in the Pipeline Class and the test proving it works.

Here a working example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Tests.Sets.Research
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TPLTest
    {
        public class PipeLine
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
            TransformBlock<int, int> b1, b2;
            ActionBlock<int> bFinal;

            static int SimulateWork(String blockName, int message, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Trace.WriteLine($"{blockName} processed: {message}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($"Fatal error {ex.Message} at {blockName}");
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
                return message;
            }


            public PipeLine(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
            {
                this.cancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;

                // Create three TransformBlock<int, int> objects. 
                // Each blocks <int, int> object calls the SimulateWork method.
                Func<string, int, CancellationTokenSource, int> doWork = (name, message, ct) => SimulateWork(name, message, ct);

                b1 = new TransformBlock<int, int>((m1) => doWork("b1", m1, cancellationTokenSource),
                   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 , CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token}); //discard messages on  this block if cancel is signaled
                b2 = new TransformBlock<int, int>((m1) => doWork("b2", m1, cancellationTokenSource), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });
                bFinal = new ActionBlock<int>((m1) => doWork("bFinal", m1, cancellationTokenSource), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });

                b1.LinkTo(b2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
                b2.LinkTo(bFinal, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
            }

            internal void Complete()
            {
                b1.Complete();
            }

            public void waifForCompletetion()
            {               
                Trace.WriteLine($"Waiting for pipeline to end gracefully");
                bFinal.Completion.Wait();
                Trace.WriteLine($"Pipeline terminated");               
            }

            public void submitToPipe(int message)
            {
                if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($"Message {message} was rejected. Pipe is shutting down.Throttling meanwhile");
                    return;
                }
                b1.SendAsync(message);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestShutdown()
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var pipeLine = new PipeLine(cancellationTokenSource);

            //post failure in 2 seconds. 
            //It would be the same if was signal from inside block 2
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Time to shutdown the pipeline!");
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            });

            //send requests to pipe in background for 5 seconds
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;

                    Thread.Sleep(50); //to see pipe closing input
                    pipeLine.submitToPipe(i);
                }
                pipeLine.Complete();
            });

            pipeLine.waifForCompletetion();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the result:

```
b2 processed: 13
b1 processed: 22
Message 45 was rejected. Pipe is shutting down.Throttling meanwhile 
b2 processed: 14
bFinal processed: 8
b2 processed: 15
bFinal processed: 9
bFinal processed: 10
bFinal processed: 11
bFinal processed: 12
bFinal processed: 13
bFinal processed: 14
bFinal processed: 15
Pipeline terminated
```

From the time Message 45 was rejected, no more messages were processed on B1.

All messages already in B2 queue reached the end of the pipeline.

Comment: As a side note, regarding the `b1.SendAsync(message)` line, it is not a good idea to fire-and-forget the [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync) task. It is preferable to `await` it, and pay attention to its return value because it can be important. If the return value is `false` it means that the offered message has been rejected, which means is practice that the block has already been completed in a canceled or faulted state, so offering more messages to it would be futile.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, it is not a good practice in general but, since in this case it is not a problem to lost messages at B1, there is no need to wait for the response. Also, this approach  will keep the thread free to fetch and post more messages to the pipeline and avoid not necessary complexity.

Comment: You have already taken measures to avoid sending messages to a dead pipeline, by checking `if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)` before the `SendAsync` command. I don't see why this check is more necessary than checking the return value of `SendAsync`. Omitting this check may not have fatal consequences, but introduces inefficiencies to the system.

Answer (score 1):

When a dataflow block [completes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.complete), it means that:

> [...] it should not accept nor produce any more messages nor consume any more postponed messages.

If you want all messages that have been successfully processed by `b2` to be processed by `bFinal`, then there are three things that you **shouldn't** do:

1. Don't define the `bFinal` block with a [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity).
2. Don't cancel the `bFinal` block.
3. Don't propagate the completion of `b2` to `bFinal`.

If you make the `bFinal` bounded, and it happens that the `b2` is faster at processing messages, then if the `b2` fails there will be processed messages stored in its output buffer. These messages will not be offered to the linked block `bFinal`. These messages will be lost.

If you do any of the 2 or 3 (cancel the `bFinal` or propagate the completion of the faulted `b2` block to `bFinal`), then the `bFinal` block will not process any message that are stored in its input buffer. It will wait until the completion of the messages that are currently in progress, and then will complete itself in a canceled or faulted state, discarding the messages in its input buffer. So don't do this:

```
b2.LinkTo(bFinal, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Do this instead:

```
b2.LinkTo(bFinal);
b2.PropagateCompletionAlwaysSuccessful(bFinal);
```

Here is the `PropagateCompletionAlwaysSuccessful` extension method:

```
public static async void PropagateCompletionAlwaysSuccessful(this IDataflowBlock source,
    IDataflowBlock target)
{
    try
    {
        await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Ignore exception
    }
    finally
    {
        target.Complete();
    }
}
```

To handle any exceptions that have occured in any of the `b2` or `bFinal` blocks, do this at the end:

```
await Task.WhenAll(b2.Completion, bFinal.Completion);
```